# Is it possible to do execute a set of steps which includes system restart in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, operating-system

I am having a project in node JS in which I have to execute a set of steps. One of such steps is system restart (I know system restart is possible). Is it possible in NodeJS to restart the system (windows) and pick up where we left and execute the remaining steps that were there after the reboot?  I have a few steps before the reboot and few steps after the reboot.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this by putting part the part of your script you want run before in one Node.js file, the part you want run after in another file, then putting everything into a [PowerShell workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/sma/overview-powershell-workflows?view=sc-sma-1801) and just running that PS script.

```
workflow Run-And-Reboot {
  node /path/to/scriptPart1.js
  Restart-Computer -Wait
  node /path/to/scriptPart2.js
}
```